# How to convert DATE in go to the data type DATE in salesforce

Tags: date, go, salesforce

I have written a service for connecting the Salesforce from Go, but the problem is I am unable to store the data in data type of DATE in Salesforce.

Does anyone have experience you can share with us?

DATE format in salesforce is ddmmyyyy(08/23/2018)

How can I get the same format in go?

This the field i have to insert in salesforce
I am sending string as my date.
    kinApplicationForm.DutyEndDate = Time().Format("8/23/2018")

Error: *http.Response=&{400 Bad Request 400 
 and is taking date as in this format "DutyEndDate__c":"8/246/24088"

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What issue are you facing? What is your output or error, and what did you expect instead?

Answer (score 3):

Read the [Go package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) documentation for time layouts.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now().Round(0)
    fmt.Println(t)
    sf := t.Format("01/02/2006")
    fmt.Println(sf)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/EX1ksiKcmKN

Output:

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
11/10/2009
```

Comment: In these format also i am unable to store the data in salesforce